# jquery - Catch only new value in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm trying to create a *JQuery* method to tell me what the user writes in a text input. For example, if there's an input with the text `foo` and the user types in `b` I want to catch that. If the user types `a` afterwards, I want to catch only that `a` and not the `ba`.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:** I did it using this code:

```
$(".writetags").each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.bind("keyup", function() {
            elem.data("oldVal", $(this).data("newVal") || "");
            elem.data("newVal", $(this).val());
            var oldVal = elem.data("oldVal");
            var newVal = $(this).val();
            console.log("Was "+oldVal+" is "+newVal);
            var newChar = newVal.charAt(newVal.length-1);
            var oldChar = oldVal.charAt(oldVal.length-1);
            console.log("The user just typed in "+newChar+" instead of "+oldChar);
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: just attach a function to the keypress event of the input element and get the pressed key from the event object

Comment: trap the keypress event

Comment: @FrebinFrancis but how would I detect the new character written in the input?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question

Comment: @TobyAllen I already did, look below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but I managed to do it using this code:

```
$(".writetags").each(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.bind("keyup", function() {
            elem.data("oldVal", $(this).data("newVal") || "");
            elem.data("newVal", $(this).val());
            var oldVal = elem.data("oldVal");
            var newVal = $(this).val();
            console.log("Was "+oldVal+" is "+newVal);
            var newChar = newVal.charAt(newVal.length-1);
            var oldChar = oldVal.charAt(oldVal.length-1);
            console.log("The user just typed in "+newChar+" instead of "+oldChar);
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a generic code that listen for all text input Changes in your web page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=text]").change(function() {
        $(this).data("oldVal", $(this).data("newVal") || "");
        $(this).data("newVal", $(this).val());
        console.log($(this).data("oldVal"));
        console.log($(this).data("newVal"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `keyCode` from the `keypress` event and use `String.fromCharCode` to get the character:-

```js
$('input').keypress(function(event){
 var character = String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.charCode || event.keyCode);
 console.log(character);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
```